# Excel Column "Mapping"

Tags: excel, xls

I am looking to "map" one Excel column to another. Column A has an ID, and Column B has a description. Column D has the same ID as Column A (but in a different order). I want Column E to return the Description from column B that is next to the appropriate ID.

In short, my logical process looks something like,

> E=B, if(A=D); if not, find B next to (A=D); OR E=B next to A=D.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to use `VLOOKUP` or `INDEX/MATCH`, try this in `E3`:

```
=INDEX(B:B,MATCH(D3,A:A,0))
```

or the `VLOOKUP` version:

```
=VLOOKUP(D3,A:B,2,FALSE)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I haven't had time to test this yet, as I found a different way to do what I needed to do (in the source program), but I'll give it a shot sometime. Thanks again! :)